# Difference between 'if not bool' and 'if bool == False'?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I used the pycharm lightbulb suggestion and changed a line in my main function from

`if check_args == False:` to `if not check_args:` but this flipped the value to true for some reason (when I moused over not it showed `bool = true`) and it made my program useless. I handed in the wrong version and now I must know what the difference is.

The odd thing is that `if check_args is False` worked fine... I was sure that the `if not value` argument is equivalent to `if value is False`.

Comment: This is not possible. Please provide a [mcve] that demonstrates the  issue.

Comment: Be careful `if not value` argument is **not** equivalent to `if value is False` for some cases, like `value = []`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if check_args is False:
    # get executed only when check_args == False

if not check_args:
    # get executed when check_args in [False, None, 0, [], {}, '']（list not exhaustive）
```

Comment: Thanks! I found out that what caused the bug is that the sub function that I was checking wasn't set to return "True" when it didn't return "False". So it was returning "None" and that's why it exited. I will be sure to add return True in the future.